# Mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl Error, Using *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I'm getting this error when I set `*ngIf` condition inside `<mat-select>`.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <mat-label>LOCATION</mat-label>
    <mat-select *ngIf="exampleObject.innerObject"  [(value)]="exampleObject.innerObject.id">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let innerObject of arrays">
            <mat-option [value]="innerObject.id">{{innerObject.location}}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

My problem is when object id is null, it doesn't exist in DB. I want to show an empty field in the dropdown list, but it's crashing on this line `[(value)]="voipDc.hepic.id"`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `<mat-form-field>`, form-field control must be within it. As stated in [Form field | Angular Material > Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol).

**Updated**: Removed previous version as Optional Chaining not supported in `[(value)]`.

You can use `&&` operator to check whether both `exampleObject.innerObject` and `exampleObject.innerObject.id` have value.

This works similarly to optional chaining to escape potential property was `null` or `undefined` and stop accessing the nested property.

```
<mat-select
  [(value)]="exampleObject.innerObject && exampleObject.innerObject.id"
>
  ...
</mat-select>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c5tqz3)

Comment: I tried that. I get an error Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 18 in

Comment: Hi, sorry for the previous answer, I had updated the solution and provide a demo. Thanks.

Comment: Tnx, it's working when it's empty, but now when i tried to update it and set id to 1, it doesn't change state

Comment: Perhaps, how about create another variable that use to hold 'example.innerObject.id' and used for mat-select. So you don't have to worry that when 'example.innerObject' is null. And while use that variable to assign value back to 'example.innerObject'.

Comment: Thank you. I figure it out. It's hacky solution bit it's working.